# How can i use "enums" in Azure app configuration section?

Tags: c#, azure

I have a c# app that i have deployed to Azure. Now there is a section in the app whereby i need to get some config settings , so i use the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VALUE")  to get the value.
But in the c# code i have a section that is as follows:

```
        switch (type)
        {
            case "client1":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("client1Value")}
                break;
            case "client2":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("client2Value")}
                break;
            case "client3":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("client3Value")}
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

The thing is here i must define 3 values in Azure config. But if i need to add a new on i need to change and recompile code.

Because in other sections of the code i need different values like

```
      switch (type)
        {
            case "client1":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("resetValue1")}
                break;
            case "client2":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("resetValue2")}
                break;
            case "client3":
                endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("resetValue3")}
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Is there a way i can do the following:

```
       endpoint = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("type")}
```

and in the config there is some sort of enum that will distinguish if it is a client 1 then give back the right config value instead of doing in code ?

Comment: `type` seems to be identical to the string being passed to `GetEnvironmentVariable`, so why not just do `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(type)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: sorry ,  let me make a change to show the situation. They can actually be different

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this problem correctly, what you need is to have mapping from "key to value", which translates to C# [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0). The only part you need to have it inside your configuration add/change those values there.

In this, it looks like you would need 2 mappings (2 dictionaries):

```cs
// Showing this as an example, normally you would deserialize them from configuration
var dictTypeToClient = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "client1", "client1Value" },
    { "client2", "client2Value" },
    { "client3", "client3Value" },
};

var dictTypeToReset = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "client1", "resetValue1" },
    { "client2", "resetValue2" },
    { "client3", "resetValue3" },
};


//To get actual value, you would just query those dictionaries:
string type = "client2";

var clientValue = dictTypeToClient[type];
var resetValue = dictTypeToReset[type];
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am after , but i want to have the key value pair in Azure. So that you just pass the type and it will return clientValue and resetValue ?

Comment: You could save it e.g. as a JSON and then load, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-leverage-json-content-type